# How do you change the background color for a band in a simile timeline?

Tags: colors, background, simile

I'm trying to change the background color of the bands I have in my simile timeline. Some of the attributes I've been using have been out of date and it's taken a while to find the latest way to call on that attribute to change part of the timeline. I currently have

```
theme.ether.backgroundColors = ["#CCCCCC","#E6E6E6","#CCFF66","#E4FF41"];
```

That line should set each band to a different background color. But it isn't doing that. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to create a CSS file and set the backgrounds there.

```
<link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

That reference goes in your html file for your timeline.

```
.timeline-band-0 .timeline-ether-bg {
    background-color: #F63BFF;
}
```

That bit of code would set the background for the first band.

This was for release 2.3.0